# API method to escalate ticket to SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using BAP creds I am able to pull all my accounts tickets, check content and update. Which API call to use to escalate ticket to SoftLayer?

Answer (score 0):

this is the API service that BAP uses to perform its actions:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand

as you can see there is a method to list the tickets, however there is no a method to create tickets, that is because when you create a ticket using BAP is the same thing like if you would create the ticket using control portal the method used is this:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket

here an example to create tickets using the Softlayer's Python client:

https://softlayer.github.io/python/create_ticket/

using REST:

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/createStandardTicket

payload:
{
    "parameters":[{
       "subjectId": 1121,
       "assignedUserId": 11111
},"this is my test ticket"]
}
```

Note: replace assignedUserId with a valid user id

Regards

Comment: Yes but still BAP control portal gives the ability to escalate the ticket to the SoftLayer. I'd like to see that in REST call so the ticket can be updated and send for further processing.

Comment: Creating a standard ticket in this case is like creating the ticket to myself, as I am using SL infastructure and resources to serve to other customers. Now in my scenario I am some sort of level support for the situations I can resolve myself. For all other cases that need SL attention I would like to have the possibility to "Escalate to SoftLayer". There is such option in control portal, when searching throught the customer tickets there is an extra option to get SL attention thru escalation. I would like to know if there is such feature thru REST. Thanks.

Comment: Oh now I undertand I did not know that was possible sorry man, I think Ruber's answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### To escalate a ticket to SoftLayer, you need to follow these steps:

**1. Add an update to the ticket**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/21588750/addUpdate

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "entry":"Escalate to SoftLayer",
         "type":  
            {  
               "keyName":"AGENT"
            }

      }
   ]
}
```

**2. Edit the ticket with the following information:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/21588750/edit

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "groupId":1008, "changeOwnerFlag":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Note: “groupId : 1008” refers to Support group. To get available group identifiers (groupId), try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/getAllTicketGroups

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Ticket::addUpdate](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/addUpdate)
- [SoftLayer_Ticket::edit](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/edit)
- [SoftLayer_Ticket::getAllTicketGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/getAllTicketGroups)